# how to package/publish a PDF for deployment?

Tags: asp.net, azure, web-deployment

i'm trying to package a deployment for Azure, but it is not packaging some files that are needed for the app to work properly. Those files are mostly PDFs and DOCXs.

If I go to the Package/Publish settings I have 3 options:
1. Only files needed to run this application. This is the default option which is excluding the PDFs and DOCXs.
2. All files in this project. This is including the missing files, but it is also including the code behind files (even though they are compiled). I do not want to include those files.
3. All files in this project folder. Haven't even tried this one because it will probably be worse than option 2.

My question is how do I set which extensions are actually needed to run this application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right after posting this question, I figured it out. For any out there with the same or similar problem here it goes...

In order to include certain files in the deployment package you have to set build action of those files to Content. Just right click on the file in solution explorer and click Properties. There change the Build Action to Content:

[image: Properties Window]

Also, you have to set the the setting of the Package/Publish to "Only files needed to run this application". The default option.

Comment: What should be the option for "Copy to output directory"?

Comment: It depends if you want that file copied to the bin folder or not. If you want it you can set it to `Always Copy` or `Copy if Newer`, otherwise leave it as `Do not copy`